# Download files pdf/jpg/png invalid in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, download, png, jpeg

I'm trying to download pdf/jpg/jpeg/png using PHP. Here is my code

```
$result= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE upload_id='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//get file extension
$filename = $row['upload_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext=='jpg'||$ext=='jpeg'||$ext=='png' ||$ext=='pdf'){
echo "<a href=\"download.php?id={$row['upload_name']} \">Download</a>";
}
```

download.php

```
$name= $_GET['id'];

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("uploads/".$name); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
exit;
```

When I tried the above code, it can be download however, when I tried opening the pdf/jpg/png it says invalid. Is there anything wrong with my code? This is my first time using the download code. So I really dont know what is the problem.

And for this path as stated in the code below,

```
readfile("uploads/".$name);
```

How do I write it if my pdf/jpg/png files are saved here in my computer C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\epals\uploads

Please help thanks

Comment: you're trying to read the ID rather than the file.

Comment: Hi may I know which part are you referring to @Fred-ii-

Comment: he meant `$name= $_GET['id'];`, is `$_GET['id']` path ?

Comment: @Jigar sorry but i dont really understand. could you explain further?